# Rendering default HTML and CSS to Sketch with react-sketchapp

Tags: reactjs, sketch-3, react-sketchapp

I've was testing the [react-sketchapp](http://airbnb.io/react-sketchapp/) which looks pretty neat so far.
Besides rendering the default sketch elements like `Text`,`View`,`Image` and so on, would it be possible to render a default react component containing HTML-Markup styled with scss?

I tried rendering the following `Hello`-Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, Artboard, Text, View } from 'react-sketchapp';

const Hello = () => (
  <View
    name={`Hello View`}
  >
    <Text name="Hello Text">
      <span>Hello World</span>
    </Text>
  </View>
);

const Document = () => (
  <Artboard
    name="Hello Board"
  >
    <Hello />
  </Artboard>
);

export default (context) => {
  render(<Document />, context.document.currentPage());
}
```

but I get the following error:
`Could not find renderer for type 'span' flexToSketchJSON`

Is rendering default react components including html / css to Sketch possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't render HTML elements to Sketch, same as you can't render HTML elements to React Native.

React is just a way of managing a tree of abstract components. How to render these components needs to be defined by the specific renderer you are using. `react-sketchapp` is a renderer that understands components which render to Sketch elements, but it does not understand HTML elements such as `div`. (and React Native includes a renderer which knows how to render React Native components to native mobile views, [react-music](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-music) is a renderer which knows how to render React Music components into audio, and so forth).

React, in and of itself, has nothing to do with HTML elements or the DOM. The `react-dom` renderer library is where the magic of rendering into the DOM happens. If you want to render HTML elements to Sketch, you'll need to write a React renderer which knows how to convert HTML elements to Sketch's file format.

Answer (score 1):

You can export any HTML/CSS to Sketch using [html-sketchapp](https://github.com/brainly/html-sketchapp).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

Try looking into using React-Primitives with React-SketchApp. 
https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-primitives

It's in a few examples within React-SketchApp e.g.
https://github.com/airbnb/react-sketchapp/tree/master/examples/profile-cards-primitives

Comment: While the links are helpful, it would be better to copy the relevant portions here in a formatted code block. [Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)